# How are monthly Stack Overflow visits calculated?

Tags: discussion

When I saw the Developer Survey results 2017 (I find it very interesting), I was wondering if the monthly Stack Overflow visits are tracked by IP address or by account, and if this number change something (ex: if the number of visited coming from China is important a Chinese `SO.ch` will be created).

Comment: Visitor statistics are probably *one* of several factors that will influence the creation of a new language Stack Overflow site - but almost certainly not the *only* factor.

Comment: @Pekka웃 can you provide please other factors

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know them for certain and could only speculate. I think they talked about this to some extent when they launched Brazilian/Portuguese Stack Overflow, but I can find only blog posts in Portuguese, which are unlikely to help either of us.